# how to get the rate of wifi connection on android?

Tags: android

I want to know if somebody can tell how can I get the rate of wifi connection on my android phone?

Comment: Programmatically, or with an [already-written app](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.org-zwanoo-android-speedtest-zBiq.aspx)?

Answer (score 5):

You find the connection speed programmatically in Android as follows:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = Context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo != null) {
    Integer linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
}
```

Note that you should use the ConnectivityManager to state your preferred network if you are anticipating use of wifi over other available networks, otherwise the speed may not actually be in use

Comment: thanks. This  method gives me the theoritical rate. I want to measure the real bandwidth.